# How to generate metrics or reports using JProfiler?

Tags: jprofiler

I have successfully started my application in Profiling mode but I am not sure how to generate reports or metrics from Jprofiler.

I could see the  Live memory (all objects, recorded objects no. of. instance count etc), heap walker etc but I am not sure of what JProfiler concludes or recommends about my application.

Can someone help?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? CPU usage, finding memory leaks?

Answer (score 1):

This profiling approach you're describing is jProfiler's live profiling session. The objective is pretty much looking at the charts it produces and identifying anomalies.

For example, on CPU profiling, you will be looking at CPU Hot Spots (i.e. individual methods that consume a disproportionate amount of time).

In memory profiler, you will be able to identify objects that occupy the most memory (also hot spots).